# How can I add a comma or separator when scraping results using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to generate my scraping result based on the following syntaks:

```
authors = item.find('ol', 'Authors')
```

The result is:

```
<ol class="Authors">
    <li><span class="author">Author 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="author">Author 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="author">Author 3</span></li>
</ol>
```

When I add `.text`, the results I have is:

```
Author 1Author 2Author 3
```

How can I convert it to:

```
Author 1, Author 2, Author 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a comma as the separator, instead of calling `.text` use the [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method with passing a comma `,` to the `separator` argument:

```
print(
    ''.join(
        tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=", ")
        for tag in soup.find_all("ol", class_="Authors")
    )
)
```

Output:

```
Author 1, Author 2, Author 3
```